# How to build a nested ordered dict from a csv?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested, ordereddictionary

How can I get a nested dictionary, where both the keys and the subkeys are *precisely* in the same order as in the csv file?

I tried

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

filename = "test.csv"
aDict = OrderedDict()

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in csvReader:
        key = row.pop("key")
        aDict[key] = row
```

where test.csv looks like

```
key,number,letter
eins,1,a
zwei,2,b
drei,3,c
```

But the sub-dictionaries are not ordered (rows letter and number are changed). So how can I populate `aDict[key]` in an ordered manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build the dictionaries and sub-dictionaries yourself from rows returned from `csv.reader` which are sequences, instead of using `csv.DictReader`.

Fortunately that's fairly easy:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

filename = 'test.csv'
aDict = OrderedDict()

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    csvReader = csv.reader(f)
    fields = next(csvReader)
    for row in csvReader:
        temp = OrderedDict(zip(fields, row))
        key = temp.pop("key")
        aDict[key] = temp

import json  # just to create output
print(json.dumps(aDict, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "eins": {
        "number": "1",
        "letter": "a"
    },
    "zwei": {
        "number": "2",
        "letter": "b"
    },
    "drei": {
        "number": "3",
        "letter": "c"
    }
}
```

Comment: One small issue: `csv.OrderedDict` skips blank lines, `csv.reader` does not.

Comment: @HaiVu: I assume you meant `csv.DictReader` skips blank lines. While true, it's trivial to emulate — just add an `if not row: continue` at the beginning of the `for row in csvReader:` loop.

Comment: Yes. that is what I meant and that is a valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

filename = "test.csv"
aDict = OrderedDict()

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    order = next(csv.reader(f))[1:]
    f.seek(0)

    csvReader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in csvReader:
        key = row.pop("key")
        aDict[key] = OrderedDict((k, row[k]) for k in order)
```

Comment: This looks fairly good and uses `DictReader()`, which I like. What I don't like is `order = next(f).strip().split(',')[1:]`, because sometimes my csv may be semicolon-separed. In my script, I use a sniffer to determine the dialect, but I skipped that here for simplicity.

Comment: You need to tell `DictReader()` to use  a semicolon too. So sniff, find the separator, go back to the beginning of the file, read the order with the separator you found and go back to the beginning file again.

Comment: +1 for your solution, however, in calculation of `order`, you need to handle not only different separators (comma, semicolon, tab, ...) but also handle quote (e.g. **"field 1","field 2"**). That is why we need to leave it to the `csv` module to handle those details and not attempt to split the fields ourselves.

Comment: Suggestion: `order = csvReader.fieldnames[1:]`. Place this right after you created `csvReader`

Answer (score 0):

`csv.DictReader` loads the rows into a regular `dict` and not an ordered one. You'll have to read the csv manually into an `OrderedDict` to get the order you need:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

filename = "test.csv"
dictRows = []

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    rows = (line.strip().split(',') for line in f)
    # read column names from first row
    columns = rows.next()
    for row in rows:
        dictRows.append(OrderedDict(zip(columns, row)))
```

Comment: This might not work if a field contains embedded comma. That is why we need to use the `csv` module. Furthermore, not all CSV file uses comma as a separator; instead they might use tab or semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the existing `csv.DictReader` class, but alter the rows it returns. To do that, add the following class to the beginning of your script:

```
class OrderedDictReader(csv.DictReader):
    def next(self):
        # Get a row using csv.DictReader
        row = csv.DictReader.next(self)

        # Create a new row using OrderedDict
        new_row = OrderedDict(((k, row[k]) for k in self.fieldnames))
        return new_row
```

Then, use this class in place of `csv.DictReader`:

```
csvReader = OrderedDictReader(f)
```

The rest of your code remains the same.